# Lookup Table vs if-else

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

Today I read code using a lookup table instead of if-else for clipping two summed uint8 values. The map is i in `i={0...255}`, and 255 in `i={256...511}`. I wondered how big the gain of this might be, and tried to find it out, using gprof,

```
g++ -std=c++0x -pg perfLookup.cpp -O2 -o perfLookup && ./perfLookup && gprof perfLookup |less
```

with the code attached below. Now without the -O2 flag gprof says that lookup() takes like 45% and ifelse() like 48% of the execution time. With -O2 though it is 56% for lookup() and 43% for ifelse(). But is this benchmark really correct? Perhaps lots of the code is optimized away since dst is never read?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

void lookup(std::vector<uint8_t> src, int repeat) {
  uint8_t lookup[511];
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    lookup[i] = i;
  }
  for (int i = 256; i < 512; i++) {
    lookup[i] = 255;
  }

  std::vector<uint8_t> dst(src.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
      dst[i] = lookup[src[i]];
    }
  }

}

void ifelse(std::vector<uint8_t> src, int repeat) {
  std::vector<uint8_t> dst(src.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
      dst[i] = (src[i] > 255) ? 255 : src[i];
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n = 10000;
  std::vector<uint8_t> src(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
    src[i] = rand() % 510;
  }

  lookup(src, 10000);
  ifelse(src, 10000);
}
```

Updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// g++ -std=c++0x -pg perfLookup.cpp  -O2 -o perfLookup && ./perfLookup && gprof perfLookup |less

std::vector<uint16_t> lookup(std::vector<uint16_t> src, int repeat) {
  uint16_t lookup[511];
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    lookup[i] = i;
  }
  for (int i = 256; i < 511; i++) {
    lookup[i] = 255;
  }

  std::vector<uint16_t> dst(src.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < src.size(); k++) {
      dst[k] = lookup[src[k]]; 
    }
  }

  return dst;

}

std::vector<uint16_t> ifelse(std::vector<uint16_t> src, int repeat) {
  std::vector<uint16_t> dst(src.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < src.size(); k++) {
      dst[k] = (src[k] > 255) ? 255 : src[k];
    }
  }
  return dst;
}

std::vector<uint16_t> copyv(std::vector<uint16_t> src, int repeat) {
  std::vector<uint16_t> dst(src.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    dst = src;
    for (int k = 0; k < src.size(); k++) {
      if (dst[k] > 255) {
    dst[k] = 255; 
      }
    }
  }
  return dst;
}

std::vector<uint16_t> copyC(std::vector<uint16_t> src, int repeat)
{
  uint16_t* dst = (uint16_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint16_t) * src.size()); // Alloc array for dst

  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    std::memcpy(dst, &src[0], sizeof(uint16_t) * src.size()); // copy src into array

    for (int k = 0; k < src.size(); k++) {
      if ((dst[k] & 0xFF00) != 0)
    dst[k] = 0x00FF;
    }
  }

  free(dst); 
  return std::vector<uint16_t>(); 
}

int main()
{
  int n = 10000;
  std::vector<uint16_t> src(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
    src[i] = rand() % 510;
  }
  std::vector<uint16_t> dst;
  dst = lookup(src, 10000);
  dst = ifelse(src, 10000);
  dst = copyv(src,   10000);
}
```

Comment: Note that you're measuring the initialization of the lookup table as part of your benchmarking. Normally you initialize a lookup table separately and don't inlcude it in the benchmarking.

Comment: I wouldn't include the initialization of the lookup table into the mesured function because this can be done only once during the execution of a program.

Comment: Some changes I would make to the code: Use the `src` argument and perform the clipping in-place --note that this is already a copy, not a reference to the original. Return that vector from the function, else the compiler could well remove all code from the functions as the local variable is never used. Create and store the lookup table outside of the test code --avoid adding operations that will not affect the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, since `src` is declared as `std::vector<uint8_t>`, `src[i]` is *never* larger than `255`, which is the highest possible value for a 8-bit unsigned integer.

Therefore, my guess is that the compiler optimizes the check away. What remains is just the boilerplate loop so the benchmark is meaningless.

*Provided the check wasn't meaningless* (i.e. check against 64 rather than 255), the result of the 'optimization' will presumably be highly machine-dependent. Branch prediction may (depending on the input data) do a good job at reducing the cost of the branch. The lookup table on the other hand needs (again depending on the input-data) random memory access and spoils the cache ...

Comment: Good point! After changing everything to uint16_t ifelse() is at 58% and lookup() is at 42%. So indeed the compiler was clever enough. (At -O3 it even optimizes out both function calls, more or less.) The distribution stays stable also when changing the number of loops, regarding building the lookup table. I wonder how this might look like in the «real» system (video editing effect, so lots of other cache accesses as well) ...

Answer (score 9):

Apart from the thing Alexander has already said:

Lookup tables *can* improve performance *drastically*. However, this is offset by the time it takes to create the lookup table in the first place. Usually you would benchmark this separately.

Another thing that has to be kept in mind is that the lookup table requires space in the cache and may therefore lead to cache misses if it’s big. If there are enough cache misses, the `if` method will be faster than the lookup table.

Finally, `gprof` is very good to identify bottlenecks. But I wouldn’t use it for benchmarks. Use a timing function instead. `gprof` uses sampling which may strictly speaking be mapped to time consumed, but is less precise here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Regarding timing functions, what are you thinking of here? Wall clock time? Or CPU cycles?

Comment: @Simon: literally doesn’t matter, once you do enough iterations (i.e. individual cycle length > 1 s) and enough repetitions of the experiment. Generally, the better the resolution the better the result. But with all the other factors that invariably influence benchmarks, don’t place too much importance in the clock.

Answer (score 3):

The handling of the `lookup` array is broken. This line:

```
uint8_t lookup[511];
```

is off by one, you want `lookup[512];` since you seem to expect to index with 511 (which accesses the 512th element). Of course, as Alexander pointed out, it's all moot anyway since `uint8_t` means you can't have an index of anything above 255.

As it is, this code:

```
for (int i = 256; i < 512; i++) {
    lookup[i] = 255;
}
```

will index out of bounds and write 255 to a more or less randomly chosen memory location.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. It should mean i<511 there. 511 should not occur since I'm adding two 8-bit numbers, the maximum is 255+255 = 510, i.e. 511 possible results.

Comment: Yes, therefore «i < 511» ;) I made a mistake with the upper bound there.

Answer (score 2):

You are measuring the time for the initialization of the lookup table as well, and this might not be what you want. If the table is only initialized once in production code, but used many times, then you should not measure the initialization.

Comment: Agreed, I would take the initialisation of the lookup table out of the `lookup` function. You could even handcode the initialisation of it and make it const (e.g. const uint8_t lookup[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3...} )

Comment: I agree; In this case building the LUT was fast enough though to have nearly no effect at all (especially when looping many times).

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches seem quite odd. Do you really need this level of optimisation?
If so then I would question the use of vectors and consider C arrays instead!

The "ifelse" approach seems more obvious. I doubt it is **noticeably** slower/faster than the lookup table unless you are calling this billions of times.

Personally I would probably just clone the src vector then iterate over it and fix the values (using 250 here because 255 makes no sense as pointed out):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> dst(src);
for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
{
    if (dst[i] > 250) dst[i] = 250;
}
```

Depending on how the cloning is actually performed and optimised by the compiler (e.g. it may do a block memory copy) then this might actually be marginally faster. It is certainly neater and easier to understand.

Comment: A similar approach would be reserving the space for the second vector --without actual copies being made, and then `std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), [](uint8_t x) { return std::min( x, 250 ) } );` (using lambda syntax for compact-ness)

Comment: Yep, this level is required. Video effect → each percent counts :) I've been told that array access is equally fast as vector access. I tried cloning, but it seems to be much slower (unless I'm doing something wrong); it compares to 80% to the copyv() function, 12% for ifelse(), and 8% for lookup(). Will add the updated code in the initial question.

Comment: @David can I use Lambda syntax in code just like in your example, or is this nod valid C++? (I tried and obtain compiler errors)

Comment: @Simon A. Eugster: mmmm surprising. Your implementation of copyv is subtly different to my suggestion, as you are creating a dst vector of the right size and then using the assignment operator, rather than just copy-constructing. But I'm surprised it is so much slower. I guess it comes down to how clever the compiler's version of vector is when it handles copy-construct or assignment.

Comment: 58/42 with >, 57.7/42.3 with &0xFF. Hardly noticeable here. OS is Linux, 64bit, 2.6.37.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the compiler is smart enough to optimize out simple profiling tests. If this is the case you have the trick the compiler into not optimizing. Using a much larger repeat value may also help give you better results or tell you if something is being optimized away.

Lookup tables can be faster than chained if/elseifs but in this case with only one comparison I wouldn't expect much difference. For example, if you had 10, 100, 1000... comparisons the lookup table should generally win.

Comment: He IS doing 10000 comparisons.

Comment: I meant having many comparisons in the same if...elseif block (i.e., one if followed by 1000 elseifs).

Answer (score 1):

A possible dirty little C solution (off the top of my head and untested/uncompiled, so probably contains mistakes):

```
std::vector<uint16_t> copyC(std::vector<uint16_t> src, int repeat)
{
     uint16_t* dst = malloc(sizeof(unit16_t) * src.size()); // Alloc array for dst

     for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
     {
         memcpy(dst, &src[0], sizeof(unit16_t) * src.size()); // copy src into array

         for (int k = 0; k < src.size(); k++)
         {
             if ((dst[k] & 0xFF00) != 0)
                 dst[k] = 0x00FF;
         }
     }

     free(dst);
}
```

I'd be interested to see how that compares. (Again it may depend on the implementation of memcpy, as it will only be faster if large memory copies are more efficient than byte-by-byte copies).

Depending on the spec of your chip (i.e. 8-bit or 16-bit register sizes), single-byte access might be faster than double-byte. if so then the code above could also be rewritten to treat dst as an array of unit8_t. Then it would only examine every second byte and if it was non-zero set it to 0 and the following byte* to 0xFF.

(* or previous byte, depending on endianness)

Comment: 44.4% for copyv, 43.9% for copyC, 6.7% for ifelse, 5% for lookup (all executed consecutively). Compiled with -O2, 100k repeats. If I change the copyv code to use &0xFF00 as well it is faster by about 1%. So the speed between those two seems to be equal.

Comment: @Simon A. Eugster: Another interesting result. Seems like the memcpy in `copyC` and vector copy in `copyV` are killing their performance. Out of interest just how big is this `src` vector and what platform are you running this on (chip and OS)? Also does using the `& 0xFF00` speed up your ifelse solution?

Comment: (Oh sorry, I didn't scroll far enough. I see src is 10,000 * uint16_t)